RAG in Google Cloud
I've created RAG in Google Cloud, but unfortunately receiving error in the response while asking for the specific item from the dataset.
I provided data Store with structured csv file, all was created successfully, then added to the tool, also quoted the tool in the agent's instructions, all seems like the tutorials

tool with well configured structured data store

Please provide info where I'm wrong

Hi , cloud you please share that CSV file .

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PU1fDtERAnSC25ZC4SOILWyV2gfHmre4TMVSXmXyeRo/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Have you tried adding space after the colon like this ${TOOL: standard1}?

it automatically removes space after saving the tool
